# How can i add members in openfire xmpp database using strophe

Tags: php, xmpp, strophe

Example: Send presence and message to xmpp openfire using strophe.js. But not insert to muc member into database. example code below

```
var pres = $pres({to: 'coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/ghywi7'})
           .c("x", { 
                  xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'
           });

var msg = $msg({to: 'coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'})
        .c("x", {
            xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'
        }).c("invite", {
            to: '1234567890@test.com'
        });
App.connection.send(pres);
App.connection.send(msg);
```

After sent this presence and message cannot insert into xmpp database ofMucMember table

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Strophe use Strophe.NS.MUC instead of 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'